# How to have two different types of users for WebAPI and MVC .netcore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating an asp.net core 2.0 app (with EFCore an Identity), which has:

1. website (MVC) where people can register and buy different plans
   (with different prices etc). So, these users must confirm e-mail and
   add other info to be able to use it's services, which include
   creating and managing mobile app users.
2. A mobile app with a WebAPI backend. Users of the app are workers
   who go from client to client, adding information that must be
   collected on-site to the app. This information is received by the
   website users.

So, the way I see it is that there are two different types of users: only one will ever use the website, and needs (more?) security since it needs a confirmed email in case he forgets password etc. Also these users will be able to see all reports and (sensitive) information gathered by the mobile app. This authentication is cookie based.

On the other hand, mobile app users are never going to have access to information other than what themselves feed into, also their e-mails are not needed. They just need a username and a code/password issued by Website user.  And this authentication is bearer token.

I would prefer to make all this in one project, so my question is how can i handle these two types of users (and authentication processes) in one project?

I read the docs on authorization schemes, claims, filters, security attributes, configuring startup.cs. I believe I could handle this if it were merely a difference in say, roles. And the questions I searched here about different types of users seemed to be really about roles, but my case i don't think it can be handled that way. For instance, Mobile app users won't register themselves nor handle passwords etc, all of this will be managed by Website users who have, say, a "full account".

If asked i may post some code, but what i really need is some guidance, for instance:

- don't do it in one project, make two, one for MVC and one for WEBAPI and handle different security/authorization/registration concerns in each;
- or: You need to create two different "AppUser" classes and (in this case, how to configure Identity / what i add to startup.cs?)

I did found this:
https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-supporting-multiple-authorization-6502eb79f934

But that's still missing the part about different users. It may well be i have read in microsoft docs and other places the info i need to do this, but i cant piece it all together - for instance, i know how to create and register a custom user class in Identity, I understand how to add filters and attributes to the MVC pipeline, and i think i need all of that to accomplish what i need, but I can't understand step-by-step what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easely achive this using ASP.net Core Authorization and Authenitcation. If you alse use Entity Framework Core you will have much help setting up all help forms in the web application.

The key for you is to set up 2 different roles. One for the mobile app and one for the web app. In the login section you check against that role and if user is in the correct role you allow the user to access the application . You have a lot of information of this online and you will find a lot of help if you search on "mvc core role based Authorization".

With this approach you will also easily set up an  admin section on the web app for handling mobile app users where you can add new users and handle their passwords.

You lose some control over your tables when you use this approach but why invent the wheel if you don't really need to?

Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking more, and also talking to my client (for whom I'm developing all this) and I'm getting to the conclusion that it all boils down to having website users need confirmed email, but not mobile app users. I configured Identity to have confirmed email for all users. If you have an idea how to accomplish this I would be grateful, but anyway I think that I may figure it out with a little more research.

Comment: You cretae the mobile app users from the website, correct? If you want to have confirmed email you can simply simulate the check and always generate a true result from it, without involving the user, when you create the mobile app user. Then when a web app user log in you check if confirmed and correct role and same check when a mobile app user log in.

Comment: As you can see I strongly advise work with the users in one table, together. In the long run it's possible to extract this to a stand alone log in service that even more aplications can use. The power of core makes its possible to create applications into microservices and deploy them in the cloud. Maybe your solution for the client isn't 2 application, maybe it is 7 different microservices that together form the impression of 2 applications?

Comment: Oh my, you are correct. I don't know why I haven't thought of (let's call it) "faking" e-mail confirmation. Thank you very much! I couldn't think of anything beyond "they're different types of users, should have two tables, two different classes and etc", which i could easily achieve if i were programming all from scratch. But this solution solves my problem, thank you again!

Comment: And yes, maybe the better solution would be something different from what I'm doing, but I used to program in PHP and used shared hosting etc. It would have been easier for me to make site and api in php, I chose to use c# because the app is xamarin forms, then I decided to go full .net. I guess learning this will also help better decide in the future what would be best for different jobs? So about microservices, it did indeed crossed my mind, but I chose to focus on efcore, c#, Identity and later study more about it. I thought it was one more thing to learn i couldn't afford right now

Comment: Maybe I was wrong? I would happily hear advice on that, in my personal circle of friends there's no one who programs, I am studying by myself. I'm prototyping this application in gcloud, my hosting provider doesn't support .net core (in the same shared server account I have other PHP websites), so since i would have to pay another account anyway I decided to try gcloud using their free credit. Since it's in the cloud is it one step closer to implement as microservices? You see, I don't know much. Guess I already wrote too much off-topic. Again, thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: It's a pleasure to help. If this is your first c# project I think microservices can be one step to much, I was just trying to make an argument for the approach I suggested. Microsrevices might be, just as you wrote, something to learn about in the future. You also made a good point about hosting and I'm glad you didn't forget that step because I had problems to find good hosting to core for a decent price. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to have one user definition for the mobile-user accessing the web-api. This user would not be authorized for the web app. You just need to make sure that when a web-api call is made from your mobile-app, it only affects the linked web-user data. I'm assuming that's what the code/password issued is for.

Comment: I think that part you say about the web-api user only affecting it's own data is correct. But after thinking more about my problem, I figured I have only one difficulty: how to make website user have required and confirmed email, and webAPI user not?